# Jtable column split

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a Jtable with 7 columns(current week's dates respectively in each column).I need to split each date column into two more sub columns(price,units).How is that possible to subdidvide a jtable column?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the `JTableHeader`object to do this.
You can find some goods examples on the web.

Comment: look a this, i think it's pretty good :
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GroupableGroupHeaderExample.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can split a JTable column but you can merge columns... I hope this would help:

[Make a cell span multiple cells](http://codeguru.earthweb.com/java/articles/139.shtml)